# Display foreach array side-by-side with CSS

Tags: php, css, arrays

I am pretty sure that if I use something like this in css

```
#list {
float:left;
}
```

I can format the display of my array to look like

```
A B C
```

rather than

```
A
B
C
```

The problem is I am having problems formatting the php of the with the proper `<div>`'s to give me what I want.

```
foreach ( $model->address as $address ) {
    if ($address->Address) echo $address->Address.'<br />';
    if ($address->city->Name) echo $address->city->Name;
}
```

Can someone help me modify the foreach above to achieve the different layout.  I also need to be able to format the `Address` differently then the `Name`

**EDIT**: For clarification...

A =

Address
City

B =

Address
    City

C =

Address
    City

Comment: Can you add the div please to see how you do it.

Comment: remove/replace the break tag: .'<br />'; with .' ';

Comment: Could you supply the array too?  I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please, describe what do you exactly want, what appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap each address in a div and use a class to float it:

PHP/HTML:

```
foreach ( $model->address as $address ) {
    echo '<div class="address-item">';
    if ($address->Address) echo $address->Address.'<br />';
    if ($address->city->Name) echo $address->city->Name;
    echo '</div>';
}
```

CSS:

```
.address-item {
     float: left;
}
```

Comment: Remove the br since it's supposed to be side by side

Comment: @Cfreak, I think this is what I need.  I want to format Address different from Name so I will just wrap each individually also

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = "<ul>";
foreach($model->address as $address){
    if(!isset($address->Address) && !isset($address->city->Name)) continue;
    $out .= "<li>" . isset($address->Address) ? $address->Address : "" . " "
        . isset($address->city->Name) ? $address->city->Name : "" . "</li>";
}
$out .= "</ul>";
print $out;
```

CSS

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
foreach ( $model->address as $address ) {
   echo '<div class="list">';
   if ($address->Address) echo $address->Address.'<br />';
   if ($address->city->Name) echo $address->city->Name;
   echo '</div>';
}
```

wherein, the CSS will be:

```
.list {float:left;}
```